# Checkbox ng-model issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

Dear Community,
                 I need to bring the company value to ng-model in check box.I have tried different ways.
     
Html code:

```
          <table>       

        <tr>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="d in matilda" ng-class-odd="odd" ng-class-even="even">
                        <td>{{d.Company}}</td>
                        <td>{{d.Contact}}</td>
                        <td>{{d.Country}}</td>
                        <td class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="d.Company" ng-false-value="''" ng-model="key"></label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        </table>
     <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-3">
                        <button class="button" ng-click="get();">View</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-3">
                        <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                            Add
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-3">

 <button class="button" ng-click="del();">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

angular code:
 // set initial value

```
  angular.module('MyApp', [])
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('TableController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
            $scope.getdeat = "";
            $scope.Company = "";
            $scope.Contact = "";
            $scope.Country = "";
            $scope.key = "";

    $scope.get = function () {
        alert("con");

    try {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: {},
            url: '/Home/Login',
            timeout: httpTimeout,
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.matilda = response.data;

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("error");
        });
    }
                        catch (ex) {alert(ex); }


            }
            $scope.add = function () {
                alert($scope.Company);
                var reg = { Company: $scope.Company, Contact: $scope.Contact, Country: $scope.Country };
                try {

                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: reg,
                        url: '/Home/AddValue',
                        timeout: httpTimeout,
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        var maxi = response.data;
                        var code = maxi.Code;
                        if (code == "1") {
                            alert("Table Updated");
                        }

                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert("error");
                    });
                }
                catch (ex) { alert(ex); }


            }
            $scope.del = function () {

                // set initial value

                alert($scope.isChecked);
                try {

                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: $scope.key,
                        url: '/Home/AddValue',
                        timeout: httpTimeout,
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        var maxi = response.data;
                        var code = maxi.Code;
                        if (code == "1") {
                            alert("Table Updated");
                        }

                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert("error");
                    });
                }
                catch (ex) { alert(ex); }


            }
}]);
```

The alert shows '' and undefined,I am a begginer,please point out where have i made the mistake,Am i making any mistake in ng-repeat section or in my js section?

Comment: Where are you using `$scope.isChecked` in your html code? Also, where is `$scope.del` called in your html code?

Comment: Sry I have changed it.Still the same error persist.

Comment: Where is `del` called? Is it outside the `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Outside in button tag

Comment: The issue here is you have declared a single variable, but you have assigned to multiple elements as the checkbox is inside the `ng-repeat` loop. So, there is no way to tell which element are you trying to delete. Do, you want to get key of only checked checkbox? what if multiple checkboxes are checked?

Comment: S,I do want the value of checked.Possible solutions????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting ng-true-value like this

```
ng-true-value="'{{d.Company}}'"
```

and since you are getting data asynchronously it is recommended to set ng-if like this

```
<table ng-if="matilda">
```

Comment: Hey can you add entire js code ? to know where exactly the problem is and are you able to see the values in the table? like company,contact,country?

Comment: S bro ,I have Added.

Comment: instead of alert do use console.log();

Comment: Noo... Empty string

Comment: it seems api issue